# addslashes not worked in php

Tags: php

i have problem with addslashes and stripslashes.
i have added data like this:

```
$data['sender_name']= addslashes($_POST['sender_name']);
$data['sender_email']= $_POST['sender_email'];
$id=insert('delivery',$data);
function insert($table=NULL,$fields=NULL)
        {
            if($table && isset($table) && $fields && isset($fields))
            {
                $sql="INSERT INTO $table(";
                foreach($fields as $key=>$value)
                {
                    $sql.="$key,";
                }
                $sql=(substr($sql,0,strlen($sql)-1));
                $sql.=") VALUES (";
                foreach($fields as $key=>$value)
                {
                    if(is_string($value))
                        $sql.="'".$value."',";
                    else
                        $sql.="$value,";
                }
                $sql=(substr($sql,0,strlen($sql)-1));
                $sql.=")";
                $flag=0;
                self::openConnection();
                mysql_query($sql,self::$connection);
                $flag=mysql_insert_id();
                self::closeConnection();
                return $flag;

            }
        }
```

it's enter the data in database but without add slashes.
magic_quotes_gpc is off.

Comment: The solution: don't use `addslashes()`. It's not meant for what you use it. Use `mysql_real_escape_string()` instead.

Comment: i'm getting this    Warning: mysql_real_escape_string() [function.mysql-real-escape-string]: Access denied for user 'jkj'@'localhost' (using password: NO) in order_info.php on line 26

Comment: for warning check: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3520079/error-while-using-mysql-real-escape-string

Answer (score 3, accepted):

instead of `addslashes` use `mysql_real_escape_string`

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php

Comment: it's give me warning like this:Warning: mysql_real_escape_string() [function.mysql-real-escape-string]: Access denied for user 'jkj'@'localhost' (using password: NO) in order_info.php on line 26

Warning: mysql_real_escape_string() [function.mysql-real-escape-string]: A link to the server could not be established inorder_info.php on line 26

Comment: i have used: $data['sender_name']= mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['sender_name']);

Comment: well, just finding out another function does not help finding the reason behind the "addslashed not worked" problem, does it? It would really be great if we could understand why it is not working.