# It says acess denied but I have the right information

Tags: php, sql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [error while using mysql_real_escape_string()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3520079/error-while-using-mysql-real-escape-string)

```
Warning: mysql_real_escape_string() [function.mysql-real-escape-string]: Access denied for user 'ksj'@'localhost' (using password: NO) in /home/ksj/public_html/cp/SuperSimpleBlogScriptV2_5_7/setup-complete.php on line 2
```

this is the file setup-complete.php

```
<?php
$site = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['site']);
$page = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['page']);
$path = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['path']);

//destroy the setup file
if(!unlink("$path/setup.php")){ /* try windows */ unlink("$path\setup.php"); }

header("Location: http://www.supersimple.org/success.php?link=$site/$page");
?>
```

Comment: You need to open a connection prior using `mres..()`. It needs a DB handle to know the right charset.

Comment: If there is a MySQL user called `ksj`, it either has a password or is not granted access from `localhost`.

Comment: Oh, and you're also using the wrong escaping function for that context. You ought to be using `urlencode()` if you throw the variables there, and `basename()` and a cleansing regex or whitelist for the $path thingy. (You shouldn't throw input variables into path strings unless you know what you're doing.)

Answer (score 2):

`mysql_real_escape_string` requires a connection which it creates implicitly if there's no active one.

Open the connection first with correct credentials using

```
mysql_connect($server, $username, $password);
```