# Only in few pages show the error Fatal Error: mysql_real_escape_string()

Tags: php, mysql

I got this error in some pages, cannot identify why it is,! please help.
thnx.,

> Fatal Error: mysql_real_escape_string(): Access denied for user
>   'flatsloo'@'localhost' (using password: NO) Fatal Error:
>   mysql_real_escape_string(): A link to the server could not be
>   established

my connection code

```
public function openConnection()
    {
        try
        {
            $this->_objMySql = mysql_connect($this->getDbConfig()->getHostName(), $this->getDbConfig()->getUsername(), $this->getDbConfig()->getPassword());

            if (mysql_errno())   // check if error occurred
            {
                return mysql_error();
            }

            mysql_select_db($this->getDbConfig()->getDatabase());

            if (mysql_errno())   // check if error occurred
            {
                return mysql_error();
            }

            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception $e)
        {
            return $e->getMessage();
        }
    }
```

Comment: have you used `mysql_connect` before this line or not?

Comment: The error describes your problem. Check your login details.

Comment: Duplicate of [error while using mysql_real_escape_string()](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3520079/1409082) and many other questions.

Comment: Could you post your connection code?

Comment: i post my connection code abow

Answer (score 1):

You have got some errors from your database connection. it failed to connect to your database. check your connection statement `mysql_connect` and its parameters.